# moq- why can't operate function with default parameter

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, tdd

I am trying to make a unit test on a very simple interface.
my interface is:

```
public interface Interface1
    {
        string retStr(string dd);
        string retStr2(string dd,string fff);
    }
```

this is the mock:

```
var myMoq = new  Mock<Interface1>();

myMoq.Setup(d => d.retStr("David")).Returns("retStr");
Console.WriteLine(myMoq.Object.retStr("fdf").ToString());
I GOT runtime error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

and another error on implementation:

```
myMoq.Setup(d => d.retStr2(It.Is<string>(e=>e=="qqq"), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns("2 parameters");
Console.WriteLine(myMoq.Object.retStr2("fdf","wewew").ToString());
```

Why is it?

Comment: One question: I'm assuming you are mocking Interface1 because it is a dependency and what you are actually testing is something else correct? If not there is really no point to testing a mock. Mocks are complementary to testing an actual implementation.

Answer (score 3):

In your setup, you are setting the expectation that a specific string will be passed in (for example "David").

You are telling Moq, "Pass back "retStr" if the method invoked with the string "David", otherwise return a default value (for string, null).  Because of this, when you do a `.ToString()` on the result of the method, the object is null.

The same thing applies to the second example.

In order to make a more general return value, use `It.IsAny<string>()` when setting up a method.  Or, do as you expect in the test and send in "David" when you call the method.